# Why my Google Maps API is not accepting API Key?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm implementing a map but I'm getting an error response and don't understand why it is not working.

Here is my attempt.

```js
var map;

function loadMap(){

 // Variable Definitions
 var mapOptions = {
  zoom: 11,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.9835464,23.7269264)
 }

 var mapid = document.getElementById('map');

 // Function call 
 map = new google.maps.Map(mapid,mapOptions)
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window,'load',loadMap())
```

```css
html, body, #map {
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}

#map {
 width: 500px;
 height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<head> 
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
  <title>Google Maps Multiple Markers</title> 
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="style.css">

</head> 
<body>
  <div id="map"></div>

  <script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3?key=API_KEY"></script>


  <!-- Script tag -->

  <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
```

In order to find a solution, I checked the console which gives me the error:

"Google Maps API error: MissingKeyMapError https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#missing-key-map-error"

So I checked the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple), but my API key seems to be right.

Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: May you add the error response to your question?

Comment: Added! Thanks for taking some interest.

Comment: You should not make your key public, some might misuse it *_^

Comment: @pedrez your API key is now mine! mwahaha

Comment: Question edited, but still it will be visible in edit history. Got a free api key for my project !

Comment: No worries, it's just a test. Already changed, thanks anyways!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your script include:

```
https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3?key=KEY
```

Should be:

```
https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&key=KEY
```

(Start with question mark, then separate parameters with &)